# How to call same wsdl from different server

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a JSF web page.This Web page is calling a .net web service from back end. I want to use this web service on different host(webservice is same just host -wsdllocation- different) but i don't want do recall wsdl from host to my JSF project. Now, im importing wsdl this command line:

```
$ wsimport -keep -verbose "wsdl url"
```

and this line have "wsdlurl" but when i upload my webservice to different webserver i must recall webservice with new "wsdlurl" after i must write new code about that. In .net this way very easy if i want to use same wsdl from different host i can just add a wsdl location line to webconfig.xml is there any way in java about this? How can i call same wsdl from different server without writing code?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the URL when creating the service object

Comment: Where can i set the object? after then import?

Answer (score 0):

By default when you import wsdl files in client and you try to open port to that service, it test the connection to a default url referenced in imported wsdl. For avoid errors first I create Service Object with the URL of the phisical file pointing to wsdl imported.

```
    URL baseUrl = <classname>.class.getClassLoader().getResource("wsdl/Service.wsdl");
    ServiceExtended service = new ServiceExtended(baseUrl);
```

In addition I use an intermediary class that extend from the original ServiceStub class, it's the way that I use for override connection-timeout and request-timeout properties for a future connection, and also you could add some layer of security using Handlers, etc.

```
public class ServiceExtended extends ServiceOriginal {
...
public ServiceExtended(URL wsdlLocation) {
    super(wsdlLocation);
}

public ProductRepository getPersonalizedPort(URL wsdlLocation, int connectTimeout, int requestTimeout) {
        ProductRepository port = super.getProductRepositoryPort();
        ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, wsdlLocation.toString());
        //JAXS-WS for compatibility
        ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout", connectTimeout);
        ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout", requestTimeout);
        //JAXS-WS new
        ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout", connectTimeout);
        ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout", requestTimeout);
        return port;
    }
...
}
```

this is an example because I save the .wsdl files using maven in "src/main/resources/wsdl/" beside META-INF, feel free to put that files where do you want. Using this way the creation of Service object will doesn't fail because you're pointing to real path, in this case to a file that exists.
After that you cant create the port to a Service pointing to any URL you want.
Would be for example:
url1 = http://server1.com/appname/Service?wsdl
url2 = http://server2.com/appname/Service?wsdl

```
ServicePort port = service.getPersonalizedPort(url1, 10000, 30000);
o
ServicePort port = service.getPersonalizedPort(url2, 10000, 30000);
```

This is an example of how you could connect to webservice.

Hope this help.